# Autofac to Common Service Locator (TypedParameter issue)

Tags: autofac, common-service-locator

How do i modify the following from Autofac to use the Common Service Locator (where _context is of type IComponentContext):

```
var query = _context.Resolve<IContentQuery>(TypedParameter.From<IContentManager>(this));
```

The code above is taken from Orchard and and i'm trying to remove the dependency on Autofac. Usually i'd try something like:

```
var query = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentQuery>();
```

However this returns null and i can't see how to handle the TypedParameter stuff as i don't understand what it's doing.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `TypedParameter` provides an additional value to the constructor of the component being resolved. In this case the underlying `ContextQuery` will accept a parameter of type `IContentManager` with the value `this` being passed.

Common Service Locator doesn't support parameterisation, so you will probably need to use the specific features of your underlying IoC container.

Hope this helps.
Nick